# Quantitative Approach to Existence of Minimal-Mass Blowup Solutions to NLS

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, blow-ups, schrodinger-operators

Consider the mass-critical defocusing NLS in dimension $d\geq 1$:

> $$iu_{t}+\Delta u = |u|^{4/d}u, \quad (t,x) \in I\times\mathbb{R}^{2}$$

Define the mass $M(u)$ and scattering size $S(u)$ of the solution $u$ respectively by

$$M(u):=\|u\|_{L_{x}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}^{2}, \quad S(u):=\|u\|_{L_{t,x}^{\frac{2(d+2)}{d}}(I\times\mathbb{R}^{d})}^{\frac{2(d+2)}{d}}$$
For a time $t_{0}$, we also define the quantities
$$S_{\leq t_{0}}(u):=\int_{I\cap (-\infty,t_{0}]}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|u(t,x)|^{\frac{2(d+2)}{d}}dxdt, \quad S_{\geq t_{0}}(u):=\int_{I\cap[t_{0},+\infty)}|u(t,x)|^{\frac{2(d+2)}{d}}dxdt$$

For mass $m\geq 0$, define the quantity $A(m)$ by
$$A(m) := \sup\{S(u) : M(u)\leq m\},$$
where the supremum is taken over all maximal lifespan solutions $u$ with mass $M(u)\leq m$. One can show that $A: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ is monotone nondecreasing, left-continuous, is finite for small $m$. Therefore there exists a unique *critical mass* $0<m_{0}=m_{0}(d)\leq +\infty$, such that $A(m)$ is finite for all $m<m_{0}$ and $A(m)$ is infinite for all $m\geq m_{0}$.

> **Conjecture 1. $m_{0} = +\infty$**

I should remark that this conjecture actually has been resolved by Benjamin Dodson in all dimensions in both the focusing (where $m_{0}=M(Q)$, $Q$ being the ground state) and defocusing cases, but I pose it anyway for the sake of the question.

In the paper ["Minimal-Mass Blowup Solutions"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609690.pdf) by T. Tao, M. Visan, and X. Zhang, the authors prove using concentration compactness, in particular a Palais-Smale condition modulo the symmetry group of the equation, that if $m_{0}<+\infty$, then there exists a maximal lifespan solution of critical mass which blows up forward and backward in time and has "some compactness" to it. More precisely,

> **Theorem 2.** If $m_{0}<+\infty$, then there exists a maximal lifespan solution $u \in C_{t,loc}^{0}L_{x}^{2}(I\times\mathbb{R}^{d})$ of mass exactly $m_{0}$ and $S_{\geq 0}(u)=S_{\leq 0}(u)=+\infty$. Moreover, there exist functions $x:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $\xi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $N:I\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that
>   $$\forall \eta>0, \exists C(\eta) > 0, \int_{|x-x(t)|\geq C(\eta)/N(t)} |u(t,x)|^{2}dx \leq \eta \tag{1}$$
>   $$\ \int_{|\xi-\xi(t)|\geq C(\eta)N(t)}|\widehat{u}(t,\xi)|^{2}d\xi \leq\eta \tag{2}$$

In a remark (see pg. 6, the paragraph below Corollary 1.20), the authors claim that one can modify the earlier "induction on energy" arguments of [Bourgain](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1626257), [CKSTT,](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2415387) and [Ryckman and Visan](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2288737) to give an alternate proof of Theorem 1. In this quantitative approach, one fixes parameters $1\gg \eta_{0}\gg \eta_{1}\gg\eta_{2}>0$, where each $\eta_{j}$ is allowed to depend on $m_{0}$ and all of the previous $\eta's$.

> **Definition 3.** A minimal-mass almost blowup solution is a solution $u$ on a compact time interval $I_{*}$ such that $M(u)=m_{0}$ and $S(u)>1/\eta_{2}$.

One can show, as is sketched in Section 8 of the cited Tao, Visan, and Zhang paper, that the frequency localization and spatial localization conditions (1) and (2) hold not for all $\eta>0$ but instead all $\eta\geq \eta_{1}$. Using these weaker localization properties, I believe that I can show the following:

> **Theorem 3.** A maximal lifespan solution $u:I\times\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $M(u)=m_{0}$ and $S(u)=+\infty$ satisfies conditions (1) and (2) for all $\eta>0$.

The *problem* is that a priori I do not know that--or at least it's not clear to me--such a minimal mass blowup solution exists, assuming of course Conjecture 1 is false. I merely know that there exist minimal mass solutions of arbitrarily large scattering size. The argument I have in mind to prove Theorem 3 proceeds by contradiction. Therefore there exists a minimal-mass blowup solution $u$ and an $\eta>0$ for which conditions (1) or (2) fail. The assumption that $S(u)=+\infty$ allows one to take the compact interval $I_{*}\subset I$ larger and larger to achieve arbitrarily large scattering size $S_{I^{*}}(u)$, without having to change functions $u$ and therefore $\eta$.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions how to get around this issue or prove Theorem 2 using the induction on mass approach, as the authors suggest one can do?